# C++ Polymorphism: Is ambiguous member type allowed?

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism

Now I need a member of an ambiguous type in a class. Here I say *ambiguous*, that means that member could be of two or more types of the same base class. See the code below.

```
class Base {
protected:
    int m_int;
    Base(int i) : m_int(i) {}
};

class Derived1 : Base {...};
class Derived2 : Base {...};

class AnotherClass {
private:
    Base m_member;  // <- this member
public:
    AnotherClass(int selection) {
        // if (selection)
        //     m_member = Derived1(...);
        // else
        //     m_member = Derived2(...);
    }
};
```

I do not know exactly how to initialize this member. Any suggestions for this? Maybe pointers / references ?

Comment: member must be a pointer (I recommend use of `std::unique_ptr`), to enable polimorphism.

Comment: The whole point of polymorphism is that you have a pointer or reference to the base class, and it points to (or references) an instance of a derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use `std::variant`, a pointer, or a type erased wrapper (EDIT: I have added a generic type erased wrapper implementation at the end). Here is the pointer solution:

```
class AnotherClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> m_member;
public:
    AnotherClass(int selection) {
        if (selection)
            m_member = std::make_unique<Derived1>(...);
        else
            m_member = std::make_unique<Derived2>(...);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, `AnotherClass` will be only movable, not copiable. If you want to be able to copy it, you must provide a copy constructor. The copy constructor has to be able to clone the member:

```
class Base {
protected:
    int m_int;
    Base(int i) : m_int(i) {}
public:
    // For covariance, return a raw pointer instead.
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
   std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override { 
      return std::make_unique<Derived1>();
   }
...
};
class Derived2 : public Base { .. same ... };

class AnotherClass {
public:
   AnotherClass(const AnotherClass & other) : m_member(other.m_member->clone()) {}
   AnotherClass(AnotherClass && other) = default;
   .... same for assignment ...
```

---

## EDIT:

An alternative is to use a type-erased wrapper, which takes care of the ugly stuff:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <class BaseType>
struct AbstractWrapper {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractWrapper() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractWrapper<BaseType>> clone() = 0; 
    virtual BaseType * get() = 0;
};

template <class BaseType, class T>
struct ConcreteWrapper : public AbstractWrapper<BaseType> {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseType, T>::value);
    T data;
    template <class U, class = std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_same_v<ConcreteWrapper, std::decay_t<U>>)>>
    ConcreteWrapper(U && value) : data(std::forward<U>(value)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractWrapper<BaseType>> clone() override
    {
        return std::make_unique<ConcreteWrapper>(*this);
    }
    BaseType * get() override { return &data; } 
};
template <class BaseType>
class TypeErasedWrapper
{
public:    
    TypeErasedWrapper(const TypeErasedWrapper & other) 
        : container(other.container->clone()) 
    {}
    TypeErasedWrapper(TypeErasedWrapper && other) = default;
    TypeErasedWrapper() {}


    template <class U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<BaseType, std::decay_t<U>>>>
    TypeErasedWrapper(U && concrete) {
        container = std::make_unique<ConcreteWrapper<BaseType, std::decay_t<U>>>(std::forward<U>(concrete));
    }
    template <class U>
    TypeErasedWrapper& operator = (U && concrete) {
        *this = TypeErasedWrapper(std::forward<U>(concrete));
        return *this;
    }

    TypeErasedWrapper& operator=(const TypeErasedWrapper & other) {
        container = other.container->clone();
        return *this;
    }

    TypeErasedWrapper& operator = (TypeErasedWrapper && other) = default;

    BaseType * operator->() { return container->get();}
    const BaseType * operator->() const { return container->get();}
    BaseType * get() { return container ? container->get() : nullptr;}
    const BaseType * get() const { return container? container->get() : nullptr;}



private:
   std::unique_ptr<AbstractWrapper<BaseType>> container;
};
```

Usage:

```
class AnotherClass {
private:
    TypeErasedWrapper<Base> m_member;
public:
    AnotherClass(int selection) {
        if (selection)
            m_member = Derived1(...);
        else
            m_member = Derived2(...);
    }
    int getValue() const {
       // Assuming getBaseValue() is a method of Base
       return m_member->getBaseValue();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static const Base& Base::getDerivedClass(int derivedID) {
    if(derivedID == 1) return Derived1();
    .... 
} 
AnotherClass(int derivedID) : m_member(Base::getDerivedClass(derivedID))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most lazy way to initialize this would be to add a parameter to the constructor.

```
private:
    Base& m_member;
public:
    AnotherClass(Base& ref) : m_member(ref) {}
```

Note though that this would be a non owning way of adding a member.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, the proper way to accomplish your goal would be to use `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

```
class AnotherClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> m_ptr;
public:
    AnotherClass (int selection) {
        if (selection) m_ptr = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
        else m_ptr = std::make_unique<Derived2>();
    }
    //...
}
```

---

You could use a *placement new*, **but it's a bad idea**.

```
union DerivedAny {
    char m_mem1[sizeof(Derived1)] alignas(Derived1);
    char m_mem2[sizeof(Derived2)] alignas(Derived2);
};

class AnotherClass {
private:
    char m_mem[sizeof(DerivedAny)] alignas(DerivedAny);
    Base * base () { return reinterpret_cast<Base *>(m_mem); }
public:
    AnotherClass (int selection) {
        if (selection) new (m_mem) Derived1;
        else new (m_mem) Derived2;
    }
    //...
};
```

Since the `m_mem` was constructed, `AnotherClass` needs a destructor to properly clean it up.

```
    ~AnotherClass () { base()->~Base(); }
```

And then you'll need to define a proper copy constructor and assignment operator. The copy constructor will be particularly tricky to implement correctly, unless you can recover the choice made by `selection`.

So this approach is fraught with pitfalls.